# String builder not using string literal from string pool. Why?

Tags: java, string

```
String s1 = "Java";
String s2 = "Java";
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();

sb1.append("Java");

System.out.println(s1 == s2);                  //true
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));             //true
System.out.println(sb1.toString() == s1);      //false
System.out.println(sb1.toString().equals(s1)); //true
```

Why is the third print statement printing false? How to make it print true?

Comment: `System.out.println(sb1.toString().intern() == s1);`

Comment: It works! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. String Interning**

As an result of Strings immutability the JVM can make optimization to store only one copy of each literal String in the Java String Pool (the special memory region where Strings are stored by the JVM). This process is called interning

If found, the Java compiler will simply return a reference to its memory address, without allocating additional memory. If not found, it'll be added to the pool and its reference will be returned.

```
String s1 = "Java";
String s2 = "Java";

System.out.println(s1 == s2); //true
```

**2. Strings Allocated Using the Constructor**

Creating a string using the `new` operator will create a new object and store it in the heap space

**Every String created like this will point to a different memory region with its own address**

```
String s1 = "Java";
String s2 = new String("Java"); //or
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();

sb1.append("Java");

System.out.println(sb1.toString() == s1);; //false
System.out.println(s2 == s1);; //false
```

**3. Conclusion**

> When we create a String object using the new() operator, it always
>   creates a new object in heap memory. On the other hand, if we create
>   an object using String literal, it may return an existing object from
>   the String pool

**4. Manual Interning**

Manually interning the String will store its reference in the pool, and the JVM will return this reference when needed

```
String s1 = "Java";
String s2 = new String("Java").intern(); //or
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();

sb1.append("Java");

System.out.println(sb1.toString().intern() == s1);; //true
System.out.println(s2 == s1);; //true
```

Comment: I didnt know about interning. This was very helpful and detailed. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Because the StringBuilder uses it's own data structure. It does not store the reference to the string, it copies it. There is no way to make it print true.

Comment: Thanks Dorian for the answer

Answer (score 2):

The implementation (at least for `Java8`) for `StringBuilder.toString()` is below:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // Create a copy, don't share the array
    return new String(value, 0, count);
}
```

Here you can see `new String(char value[], int offset, int count)` is called so `==` will be `false`.

You can test the equivalent code manually below:

```
String s1 = "Java";
String s2 = "Java";
System.out.println(s1 == s2); //true
System.out.println(new String(s1) == s2); //false
System.out.println(new String(s1.toCharArray(), 0, 4) == s2); //false
```

Here you can see `new String()` creates a new Object so `==` is false.

This can also be seen in the documentation for `new String`:

> Initializes a newly created {@code String} object so that it
>   represents    the same sequence of characters as the argument; in
>   other words, the    newly created string is a copy of the argument
>   string. Unless an
>     explicit copy of {@code original} is needed, use of this constructor
>   is   unnecessary since Strings are immutable.

Note:  `Java9+` uses `byte []` instead of `char []` behind the scenes for `String`, so some of the specifics may have changed, but the idea stays the same.

Comment: Thanks Nexevis for the detailed explanation with examples.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a couple of more lines to your code to make it clear for you. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "Java";
        String s2 = "Java";
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        sb1.append("Java");
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
        System.out.println(sb1.toString() == s1);
        System.out.println(sb1.toString().equals(s1));

        String s3 = new String("Java"); // It's a new String similar to what sb1.toString() returns
        System.out.println(s1 == s3);// false
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
false
true
false
```

Do check [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/StringBuilder.java) to explore how `StringBuilder::toString` has been implemented.

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful.